# How can I get the name of the file system currently called?

Tags: c++, arduino, filesystems, esp32

I am using an ESP32 in an Arduino environment and I use both an SD-card and the flash memory. Conveniently, the file system calls are (almost) the same for both, so e.g. this function:

```
void listDir(fs::FS &fs, const char * dirname, uint8_t levels){
```

works equally for either device by using fs as either 'FFat' or 'SD', and likewise other functions for read, write and other.

However, sometimes I need to know which filesystem was used. How can I find out whether fs was called as 'FFat' or 'SD'?

Comment: at compile time or at runtime?

Comment: Couldn't you check `const char* name() const;` from the FS class?

Comment: runtime. At compile time I can still keep track (though barely so, sometimes, ;-))

Comment: @theSealion: can you give a piece of code, I could test? I have run out of ideas. Last thing I tried was 'typeid(fs).name()', but that gave me a compile error ' cannot use typeid with -fno-rtti' . I have no idea what it means.